# Kotlin coroutine observer

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, grpc, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing GRPC server with Spring, Kotlin and Coroutines. My rpc service looks like this:

```
override fun authToken(request: AuthTokenRequest): Flow<AuthTokenResponse> {
    return flow<AuthTokenResponse> {
        while (true) {
            delay(1000)
            emit(AuthTokenResponse.newBuilder().setToken("Hello").build())
        }
    }
}
```

I wanna wait until somebody else change values in DB, connect to server and etc. in this case i need to emit new Response. Meanwhile clients still hangs on stream. What concept or design pattern I should use? Thanks for replies

Comment: If you are not receiving pushes from the service  about a changed value, then you have no choice but to poll from your side. After your `delay` call, check the DB value. If it has changed from the last value you emitted, then emit it.

Comment: @Laurence I could receive push from Account service that somebody change values, but I have no idea how to tell it to this Flow. I don't want to have this while{}. I need something like global context of Flows(Streams)

Comment: So you will have something lke a websocket? If so, when you start you need to start your own coroutine Publisher that itself connects to that websocket and waits for the pushes.

Your publisher should implement a subscribe funciton that produces a flow or takes a flow.

When your publisher recieves a new message from it's socket, then it shoudl forward it on to any subscribing flows.